# Switch to 32-bit Protected Mode causes QEMU to restart in a loop

Tags: assembly, x86, qemu

boot.asm:

```
[org 0x7c00]
[BITS 16]
boot:
    mov bp, 0x9000 ; set the stack
    mov sp, bp

    mov bx, MSG_REAL_MODE
    call print_string

    call switch_to_pm

    jmp $

%include "print/print.asm"
%include "gdt.asm"
%include "print_32.asm"
%include "switch_to_pm.asm"

[BITS 32]

; We're in 32-bit Protected Mode
BEGIN_PM:
    mov ebx, MSG_PROT_MODE
    call print_string_pm

    jmp $

MSG_REAL_MODE:
    db "Started in 16-bit Real Mode", 0

MSG_PROT_MODE:
    db "Sucessfully landed in 32-bit Protected Mode", 0

; Bootsector padding
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

gdt.asm:

```
[BITS 16]
align 4

gdtr:
    dw gdt_end-gdt_start-1
    dd gdt_start
; GDT
gdt_start:
    dd 0x0 ; 'dd' means define double word (4 bytes)
    dd 0x0

gdt_code: ; the code segment descriptor
    ; base=0x0, limit=0 xfffff,
    ; 1st flags: (present)1 (privilege)00 (descriptor type)1 -> 1001b
    ; type flags: (code)1 (conforming)0 (readable)1 (accessed)0 -> 1010b
    ; 2nd flags: (granularity)1 (32 - bit default)1 (64 - bit seg)0 (AVL)0 -> 1100b
    dw 0xffff ; Limit (bits 0-15)
    dw 0x0 ; base (bits 0-15)
    db 0x0 ; base (bits 16-23)
    db 0x9A ; 1st flags, type flags
    db 11001111b ; 2nd flags, linit (bits 16-19)
    db 0x0 ; base (bits 24-31)

gdt_data: ; the data segment descriptor
    ; same as code segment execpt for the type flags:
    ; type flags: (code)0 (expand down)0 (writable)1 (accessed)0 = 0010b
    dw 0xffff ; Limit (bits 0-15)
    dw 0x0 ; base (bits 0-15)
    db 0x0 ; base (bits 16-23)
    db 0x92 ; 1st flags, type flags
    db 11001111b ; 2nd flags, linit (bits 16-19)
    db 0x0 ; base (bits 24-31)

gdt_end: ; the reason for putting a label at the end of the
         ; GDT is so we can have the assembly calculate
         ; the size of the GDT for the GDT descriptor (below)

; GDT descriptor
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; size of the GDT, always less one
                               ; of the true size

    dd gdt_start ; start address of the GDT

    ; define some handy constants for the GDT segment descriptor offsets, which
    ; are what segment registers must contain when in protected mode
    ; (0x0 = NULL; 0x08 = CODE; 0x10 = DATA)
    CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
    DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

print_32.asm:

```
[BITS 32]
; Define some constants
VIDEO_MEMORY equ 0xb8000
WHITE_ON_BLACK equ 0x0f

; prints a null-terminated string pointed to by edx
print_string_pm:
    pusha
    mov ah, WHITE_ON_BLACK ; Set edx to the start of video memory

print_string_pm_loop:
    mov al, [ebx] ; store the char at ebx in al
    mov al, WHITE_ON_BLACK ; store the attributes in ah

    cmp al, 0 ; if (al == 0), at end of string, so
    je print_string_pm_done; jump to print_string_pm_done

    mov [edx], ax ; store char and attributes at current character cell

    add ebx, 1 ; increment ebx to the next char in the string
    add edx, 2 ; move to next character cell in video memory

    jmp print_string_pm_loop

print_string_pm_done:
    popa
    ret ; return from the function
```

The only reason I know of that would cause QEMU to just restart in a loop is a triple fault, but I have no idea where that's coming from.

I've tried logging the QEMU interrupts with `-d int` but I have no idea what it means whatsoever. Here's the output log file:

```
SMM: enter
EAX=00000001 EBX=0000000b ECX=02000000 EDX=02000628
ESI=00000000 EDI=02000000 EBP=07fa84c0 ESP=00006c80
EIP=000ebad0 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6070 00000037
IDT=     000f60ae 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00007113 CCD=00000001 CCO=LOGICB  
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=00000001 EBX=0000000b ECX=02000000 EDX=02000628
ESI=00000000 EDI=02000000 EBP=07fa84c0 ESP=00006c80
EIP=000ebad0 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6070 00000037
IDT=     000f60ae 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7cd9 ECX=00001234 EDX=0000db80
ESI=07fbdb3b EDI=00006c40 EBP=00006c00 ESP=00006c00
EIP=00007cd8 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db80 000db800 ffffffff 008f9300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 008f9b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
GS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000004 CCD=00006c00 CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7cd9 ECX=00001234 EDX=0000db80
ESI=07fbdb3b EDI=00006c40 EBP=00006c00 ESP=00006c00
EIP=000f7cd9 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6070 00000037
IDT=     000f60ae 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007cf3 ECX=00005678 EDX=000eac40
ESI=07fbdb3b EDI=000eac40 EBP=00006c00 ESP=00006c00
EIP=000f7cf2 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6070 00000037
IDT=     000f60ae 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00006bec CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007cf3 ECX=00005678 EDX=000eac40
ESI=07fbdb3b EDI=000eac40 EBP=00006c00 ESP=00006c00
EIP=00007cf3 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db80 000db800 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000004 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7cd9 ECX=00001234 EDX=0000db80
ESI=07fbdb3b EDI=0000692e EBP=000068ee ESP=000068ee
EIP=00007cd8 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db80 000db800 ffffffff 008f9300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 008f9b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 008f9300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 008f9300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000004 CCD=000068ee CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=000f7cd9 ECX=00001234 EDX=0000db80
ESI=07fbdb3b EDI=0000692e EBP=000068ee ESP=000068ee
EIP=000f7cd9 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6070 00000037
IDT=     000f60ae 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: enter
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007cf3 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=07fbdb3b EDI=00000000 EBP=000068ee ESP=000068ee
EIP=000f7cf2 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6070 00000037
IDT=     000f60ae 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=000068da CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=000000b5 EBX=00007cf3 ECX=00005678 EDX=00000005
ESI=07fbdb3b EDI=00000000 EBP=000068ee ESP=000068ee
EIP=00007cf3 EFL=00000006 [-----P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =db80 000db800 ffffffff 00809300
CS =f000 000f0000 ffffffff 00809b00
SS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
DS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
FS =0000 00000000 ffffffff 00809300
GS =ca00 000ca000 ffffffff 00809300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 00000000
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=00000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=00000004 CCD=00000001 CCO=EFLAGS  
EFER=0000000000000000
```

No idea what's wrong. The log file just repeats that block of text over and over (which makes sense, as it was restarting in a loop)

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping your code with the debugger?  Bochs has a more convenient debugger than QEMU for this.

Comment: You've also omitted several of the source files, and we have no indication as to which of them is causing the bug, so this isn't a [mcve].

Comment: @NateEldredge (Response to 1st comment) I have no idea how to do that. I'll see if I can figure out how.

Comment: Yeah, using a debugger is an essential technique for assembly programming.  You will just spin your wheels without one.  Frankly I would suggest learning to use a debugger before you write a single line of code.

Comment: @NateEldredge (Response to 2nd comment) I don't know which one it is either. So I can't really only show 1 or 2 files when I have no idea what/where it's going wrong, or what is causing it, or I would've been able to fix it.

Comment: @NateEldredge I know how to use a debugger, I just don't know how to enable it in Bochs.

Comment: But you know the general process for making a minimal example?  Cut out pieces of your code until the problem no longer arises.  Then put back whatever seems to have caused it.  Then cut out other stuff that isn't relevant either.

Comment: @NateEldredge When 99% of your code is dependent on other code, you can't really do that (e.g the print_string_pm function being required for logging if it gets to 32-bit Protected Mode, and I have no idea if that works properly either)

Comment: If you really can't reduce it, then just go ahead and post all the files.  The easiest way for the bug to be found is for someone to actually run the code.  Btw, you probably found [this info on the Bochs debugger](https://bochs.sourceforge.io/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html)?  If you happen to be on Ubuntu, the standard bochs package has the debugger already enabled at compilation.

Comment: @NateEldredge When I try to use the print_string_pm function while in real mode, it just doesn't work. When using print_string it works fine. Here's a GitHub repo I just set up: https://github.com/ThatCodingGuy86/TestOperatingSystem                           Oh, and I'm not on Ubuntu and I really don't want to compile Bochs (as far as I can tell, you're supposed to compile Bochs with some extra options to enable debugging)

Comment: Well, you can use QEMU's debugger (remote gdb) if you really want, e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Debugging_with_QEMU.  It's just kind of a pain in real mode because gdb doesn't understand segment:offset addressing, so you have to work out all the linear addresses yourself in order to set breakpoints or inspect data.  I seem to recall there are also some issues with getting it to disassemble in the right mode.

Comment: I just tried one of the methods of debugging in your link, it just gave me this output that I can't make heads or tails of: https://pastebin.com/dKPbTcFh

Comment: This might be a question for a QEMU support forum; I don't know if I can help with it.  It sounds like perhaps your installed version of gdb doesn't contain the necessary support for talking to a QEMU instance.  This could be something specific to Cygwin (is that what you're using?) which I don't know very much about.

Comment: If QEMU isn't working easily, use Bochs' built-in debugger.  Like Nate said, it's better anyway, so it's worth taking whatever time is necessary to get it installed.  Either way you basically *need* a debugger, otherwise you're wasting tons of time guessing about what might be going wrong.  (And wasting other people's time asking about code you haven't used a debugger on.)  Your QEMU log appears to just show entering System-Management Mode and leaving it (ReSuMing normal execution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The *print_string_pm* has multiple issues!

> ```
> mov ah, WHITE_ON_BLACK ; Set edx to the start of video memory
> ```

The code does not setup the video output address in `EDX`. Depending on the pre-existing value in `EDX`, you might be destroying something important!

---

> ```
> mov al, WHITE_ON_BLACK ; store the attributes in ah
> cmp al, 0 ; if (al == 0), at end of string, so
> je  print_string_pm_done
> ```

To make matters worse, these lines will make the loop never end (WHITE_ON_BLACK is non-zero). So the above mentioned destroying is guaranteed to happen (I believe).

Try next code:

```
VIDEO_MEMORY equ 0xB8000
WHITE_ON_BLACK equ 0x0F

; prints a null-terminated string pointed to by EBX
print_string_pm:
    pusha
    mov   edx, VIDEO_MEMORY
    mov   ah, WHITE_ON_BLACK
print_string_pm_loop:
    mov   al, [ebx]
    cmp   al, 0
    je    print_string_pm_done
    mov   [edx], ax
    add   ebx, 1
    add   edx, 2
    jmp print_string_pm_loop
print_string_pm_done:
    popa
    ret
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that EDX would even have any pre-existing values.. (although, in hindsight, that should've been obvious)

Answer (score 1):

I've just fixed it. After applying the fix @SepRoland gave me in his answer, I realized on line 17 of [switch_to_pm.asm](https://github.com/ThatCodingGuy86/TestOperatingSystem/blob/main/switch_to_pm.asm), I put `init_pm` instead of `CODE_SEG:init_pm`, so instead of preforming a far jump, I accidentally preformed a short jump. My code now works, thanks everyone.